# Ignore invalid SSL Certificates firefox

Tags: protractor

I would like to run my tests on firefox. I'm always getting an invalid SSL Certificates error, even though acceptSslCerts and trustAllSSLCertificates are set to true in the config file.

I'm starting a standalone selenium webdriver by specifying the path to the gecko driver.

Any suggestions ???

Thanks!!